# Is Struts-core-6.X.X compatible with Jakartaee 10?

Tags: struts2, compatibility, java-11, migrate, payara

I am migrating my struts-application from Javaee 8 to Jakartaee 10, Payara 5 to Payara 6(use community version) and Jdk8 to JDK 11.

Currently, I am using struts-core-2.5.26. Is latest version of struts-core-6.x.x compatible with Jakartaee 10? or Any of struts2 version supports Jakartaee 10?

Trying to migrate struts2 web application from javaee8 to Jakartaee 10. And Expect to migrate it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

From the Struts documentation, I don't see any mentions of Jakarta EE 10 compatibility on their website.

It is not clear but looks like Struts 2 is compatible only up to Java/Jakarta EE 8.
Payara 6 only supports Jakarta EE 10.

So, it's better to stick with Jakarta EE 8 and Payara Enterprise 5 (Java/Jakarta EE 8) as Payara Community versions prior to 6 are no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

The latest struts2 version, 6.3.0.1, supports only JEE 8 / Jakarta EE 8 or earlier.

**(Personally I have not tried this approach yet)**:
However, you could try to put your war file under $CATALINA_BASE/webapps-javaee of your tomcat 10 or newer.

Basically, you will have a struts2 app using JEE8/JakartaEE8 and be able to run on Tomcat10 or newer.

Reference:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-5110
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/WW/issues/WW-5141?filter=allopenissues
- https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/host.html